# Javascript array check and combine

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays containing some objects and I need to know how to combine them and exclude any duplicates. (For example, the object that contains `apple: 222` from the second array should be excluded, if it already exists in the first array.)

Check below:

```
var arr1 = [
    {apple: 111, tomato: 55},
    {apple: 222, tomato: 55}
]

var arr2 = [
    {apple: 222, tomato: 55},
    {apple: 333, tomato: 55}
]
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
   var res = [
    {apple: 111, tomato: 55},
    {apple: 222, tomato: 55},
    {apple: 333, tomato: 55}
]
```

How can I do that in javascript?

Comment: Those "inner arrays" are javascript objects, FWIW.

Comment: Please post array literals (and not PHP)

Comment: Your array begin by '(' and finish by '}'  ???

Comment: Look up Array's concat method.

Comment: Not sure why you changed the example code, but I've amended my answer to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solution fit with your needs ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wared/FTVPC/)) ?

```
var res, i, item, prev;

// merges arrays together
res = [].concat(arr1, arr2);

// sorts the resulting array based on the apple property
res.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.apple - b.apple;
});

for (i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    item = res[i];

    // compares each item with the previous one based on the apple property
    if (prev && item.apple === prev.apple) {

        // removes item if properties match
        res.splice(i, 1);
    }
    prev = item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a dedupe function.

```
if (!Array.prototype.dedupe) {
  Array.prototype.dedupe = function (type) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
      if (this[i][type] === this[i + 1][type]) {
        this.splice(i, 1);
        i--; l--;
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
}

function combine(arr1, arr2, key) {
  return arr1
    .concat(arr2)
    .sort(function (a, b) { return a[key] - b[key]; })
    .dedupe(key);   
}

var combined = combine(arr1, arr2, 'apple');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNaWb/3/).